# Richfaces inputText onBlur and commandButton onClick

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a page with two text fields and a `commandButton`, in one of the text field `onBlur` i'm calling `onBlur()` method in the bean and in the `commandButton` i'm calling `onClick()` method in the bean, every thing works fine except when i click the `commandButton` if the focus is on the text box with `onBlur` then only the `onBlur` method been called not both. I've attached the xhtml file and bean.

XHTML Code

```
<h:inputText id="service" value="#{onBlurTestBean.service}">
  <a4j:support status="test" event="onblur"
    action="#{onBlurTestBean.onBlur}"  reRender="category" />
</h:inputText>
<a4j:htmlCommandLink id="submit" action="#{onBlurTestBean.onClick}"
  ajaxSingle="true" value="Click!" />
```

Bean

```
public class OnBlurTestBean {
    private String service;
    private String category;
    public void initialize(){
    }
    public void onBlur(){
        log("onBlur");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    public void onClick(){
        log("OnClick");
    }
    public void log(String msg){
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you provide 'xhtml file and bean'

Comment: @Andreay I cant attach files here but i updated my post with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified example in question works OK (both methods are invoked onBlur and onClick).
In you case it seems you have `a4j:status` component which blocks user clicks (for example covers the layout with invisible div).

To verify my assumption, try the following (`status` attribute removed, `a4j:region` added):

```
<a4j:region>
    <h:inputText id="service" value="#{onBlurTestBean.service}">
        <a4j:support event="onblur"
            action="#{onBlurTestBean.onBlur}"  reRender="category" />
    </h:inputText>
</a4j:region>
<a4j:htmlCommandLink id="submit" action="#{onBlurTestBean.onClick}"
        ajaxSingle="true" value="Click!" />
```

Comment: Andrey, if the a4j:status is removed its working but the requirement is we have to block any modification in the form before the current request. is there any way to achive this?

Comment: @Karthikeyan According to that requirements your form works as expected (blocks modifications/button clicks until request is processed). You need a4j:region around your inputs and custom a4j:status inside of the region which does not block the button. Personally I would prefer no blocking on blur event (just wrap inputs with a4j:region).